# Problems when remove a specific element from array by removeAtIndex(Index: Int) function

Tags: arrays, swift, indexing

Thanks for your attention

The task is to write a function that removes the first occurrence of a given integer from an array of integers.

There is my solution:

```
func removeOnce(itemToRemove: Int, fromArray:[Int]) -> [Int]{
    var resultArray = fromArray

    if let index = fromArray.indexOf(itemToRemove){
        resultArray = resultArray.removeAtIndex(index)
        return resultArray
    }
}
```

I've got an error, because the agument for function ***removeAtIndex(Index: Int)*** should be an Int type, however the index varialbe is the index type. I guess I can convert "Index" type to "Int" type somehow, but is there a better way to sovle this problem without any type convertion?

Comment: Use `indexOfObject(anyObject: AnyObject)`. That will make index an int. Which will solve part of your problem. also call `removeAtIndex` in place and then return result array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[removeAtIndex(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Array_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/structm/Array/s:FSa13removeAtIndexFSix) removes an element at that index from the array, and returns the element, not the array. The array is edited in place, so either return `resultArray` or, change your method to not return anything (as the removal is done in-place, on the existing array, and doesn't return a modified copy).

Comment: If you change the method to not return anything, then `fromArray` will have to be declared as `inout` so that the passed array will be modified.

Comment: Better yet, write a protocol extension.

Comment: Well there's no indication this function doesn't already reside in a protocol extention

Answer (score -2):

```
func removeOnce(itemToRemove: Int, fromArray:[Int]) -> [Int]{
    var resultArray = fromArray

    if let index = fromArray.indexOf(itemToRemove){
        resultArray.removeAtIndex(index)
    }
    return resultArray
}
```

Comment: You can get rid of the first return because it will just hit the second one anyway.

Comment: You can also use `var fromArray = fromArray` and not have to use a second arbitrary name like `resultArray`

Comment: Or maybe you can use in_out parameter for second argument fromArray, then you don't have to do the decleartaion var fromArray